# Cannot assign argv to an array

Tags: arrays, c, argv

I am trying to assign the input on a command line of argv to my char networks, but i keep getting an error that says

```
assignment to expression with array type
   28 |                 networks[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

i am wondering how i could assign argv into the networks char. please let me know.

thank you

```
 14 int main(int argc, char** argv){
 15     for (int j =0; j<1; ++j){
 16         if(argc == 1)
 17              {
 18                 printf("ERROR ERROR, you messed up");
 19             }
 20
 21         else
 22         {
 23         // hold network addresses in a 2-d array, with 4 unsigned char
 24             unsigned char networks[argc][4];
 25
 26         //store argv into networks using atoi
 27             for (int i = 0; i<argc; ++i){
 28                 networks[i] = atoi(argv[i]);
 29                 printf("\t%hhu\n", networks[i]);
 30
 31         }
 32         }
 33         }
```

Comment: `argv` is of formal type `char *[]` (an array of pointers), `network` is a 2D array of `unsigned char`, e..g formal type `unsigned char (*)[4]`. The types do not match. `networks[i] = atoi(argv[i]);` tries to assign an `int` to an array of `unsigned char`. An array is not an *lvalue*.

Comment: is there any way to change argv so that i can equate them?

Comment: `unsigned char networks[argc];` will create an array (a VLA) of `argc` `unsigned char`. Then assigning `networks[i] = atoi(argv[i]);` will work. (though since `atoi()` returns type `int`, you are better using `int networks[argc];`) Also note `atoi()` provides zero error detection and will happily fail returning `0` silently for `atoi ("my cow");`, better to use `sscanf()` or `strtol()` for the conversion.

Comment: sorry didnt read code properly.. i deleted my comment. i am newbie here ;_;

Comment: No worries -- I've been guilty of the same (even tonight...)

Comment: well i cant change my unsigned char variable, is there a way to read the input and place it directly into networks?

Comment: Yes, you just have to check (validate) that the converted value is within the range of `unsigned char`. Hold on, I'll give a minimal example.

Comment: regarding: `for (int i = 0; i<argc; ++i){ networks[i] = atoi(argv[i]);`  argv[0] is a char pointer to the name of the program being executed.  Therefore, very unlikely to be a numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When converting a string to integer value, be aware that `atoi()` provides zero validation of the conversion and will silently fail returning zero for any non-numeric string given (e.g. `atoi("My Cow");` silently fails returning `0`). A minimal validation can be provided by `sscanf()`, and full validation can be provide by `strtol()` (or `strtoul()`, etc...)

In your case `networks[i] = atoi(argv[i]);` tries to assign an `int` to an array of `unsigned char`. That won't work because an array is not an *lvalue* (see: [C11 Standard - 6.3.2.1 Other Operands - Lvalues, arrays, and function designators(p3)](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3))

What you are attempting can be done by simply creating an array of `unsigned char` (a VLA in  your case) Note: as of C11, compiler support for *Variable Length Arrays* is optional -- but most will continue to provide support.

A minimal example that validates the input using `sscanf()` can be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    
    unsigned char networks[argc];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < argc - 1; i++) {                /* loop argc - 1 times */
        unsigned char temp;                             /* temporary unsigned char */
        if (sscanf (argv[i+1], "%hhu", &temp) == 1) {   /* convert/validae argv[i+1] */
            networks[index] = temp;                     /* on success, assign */
            index += 1;                                 /* increment index */
        }
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++)                     /* loop index times */
        printf ("networks[%d] = %d\n", i, networks[i]); /* output results */

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `%hhu` is the proper conversion specifier for use when converting to `unsigned char`)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/argv_networks 10 20 30 banana 40
networks[0] = 10
networks[1] = 20
networks[2] = 30
networks[3] = 40
```

(**note:** the invalid input `"banana"` is simply ignored by validating the result of the conversion)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.